# How to transport turtle and fish via airline?

Tags: fish, turtles, house-moving

I may relocate to another country. How can I manage a flight transport for my turtle and fish? Is it realistic to do so in general?

The flight is approximately 3-4 hours.

The fish are black mollies, guppies, welsh and goldfish.

The turtle is a yellow bellied slider with an approximately 20-30 cm carapace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing you need is to find what rules and regulations the country you're moving to has for this, and you'll need to be prepared to pay first for the transport and then for the quarantine for the time determined by officials at your destination.

There are companies that are specialized in moving live animals; you need to contact one of them. (I cannot give you the names here but there are several companies doing air transport.) These are international companies doing world wide transport.

Your turtle will probably need to be vaccinated and your vet needs to provide documentation for the vaccination.

Companies where I live do import live fish from Japan (mostly koi and goldfish); they have to keep the fish in quarantine for a predetermined time controlled by a vet and undergo health and safety inspections.

I believe moving your fish and your turtle will cost more than it will cost you to get new ones at your destination.

Comment: And there may be security problems with the airlines. Physically it is no problem as many fish are shipped in Styrofoam boxes with proper documentation.

Comment: @blacksmith37 i do not mention styrofoam boxes in my answer but yes this is how it is done by the companies i mention :)

Comment: indeed for fishes like this I would not hesitate to give them to someone or to a petshop before considering moving them via a plane. There is a high risk for their health too. For the turtle I understand you would want to keep it.

Comment: Most time it is easier to find a new nice place for fishes, than for a turtle... Thank you for your answer, the last sentence is a little bit hard, may have reason in "no English mother tongue" of mine. Because the stay is for approx. 2 years, "turtle holiday" by a friend is a possibility...

Comment: @Allerleirauh it was not clear to me how long your stay might be,so i answered as if it was permanent.sorry for beeing wrong on this :) but our life is always changing so nobody can say what the future will bring,you might find a reason to stay or a reason to move back :)

Comment: I let out the time factor willful, because it will not affect the question. With the information from your answer I can decide well-considered what solution is best for me and my animals :)